# Combinations in java

Tags: java, combinations, hamming-distance

I write a java code to write all combinations of bit string with length N" .  this code print all combination but I want to have all combination with exactly N length and "H" 1's.

like N=4 & H=2 => 0011,0101,0110,1100,1010,1001

```
public void print(int n, char[] k, char[] A) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(A) + " ");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
            A[n - 1] = k[i];
            print(n - 1, k, A);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String k = "01";
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    MiniProject i = new MiniProject();
   i.print(n, k.toCharArray(), new char[n]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

(1) Before your `System.out.print`, count the number of 1's in `A` and see if it matches the count you want.

(2) Define your recursive method to be

```
public void print(int n, char[] k, char[] A, int numberOfOnes) {
```

Then:

- When you call `print` recursively, the last parameter will depend on whether you just added a 1 or a 0 to `A`.  If you added a 0, then `numberOfOnes` will be the same as the value that was passed in.  If you added a 1, then use `numberOfOnes - 1` when you call recursively.  For example, say `n=4` and you want to generate all 4-bit bit strings with 2 ones.  If you set the first bit to 0, you will now want to generate all 3-bit strings with 2 one bits.  But when you set the first bit to 1, you will want to generate all 3-bit strings with 1 one bit, since you already used up one of the 1's.
- Base cases: If `numberOfOnes` is 0, then just generate `n` 0 bits as the only solution.  If `numberOfOnes` is greater than `n`, don't generate anything--it will be impossible.